# Test the JSON response using rspec rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, rspec

I get all the responses from JSON in **rails(API)**. How should I test the responses from **JSON using rspec gem(CRUD operations)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Couple of ways.

1. You could validated it as a string.
2. You could parse `JSON.parse(response)` the response string, validate specific elements of the response.

Are something I can recommend.